# How to get Entity Framework to read my app.config file in Unit Test project

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to create a database for my entity framework tests, but I can't get it to read my configuration files correctly. My `app.config` file in test project looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestConnection"
         connectionString= "Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
                            Initial Catalog=LocabalTestDB;
                            Integrated Security=SSPI;
                            MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  ....
</configuration>
```

However, it is not creating a database called `LocabalTestDB`, it is creating a database called `Locabal.Model.LocabalSqlContext`, and this is what the connection string looks like:

> "Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Locabal.Model.LocabalSqlContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFrameworkMUE"

This is what the DB creation/seed code looks like (it runs once before I run any tests):

```
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void Init(TestContext c)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<LocabalSqlContext>(null);

        using (var db = new LocabalSqlContext())
        {
            if (!db.Database.Exists())
            {
                db.Database.Create();
                Locabal.Model.Migrations.Configuration.SeedData(db);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this app.config in the test project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-walkthrough.aspx), you have to set the name in connection string to the name of your `DbContext`, then the "Initial Catalog" parameter will be your DB name. For example:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocabalSqlContext"
         connectionString= "Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
                            Initial Catalog=LocabalTestDB;
                            Integrated Security=SSPI;
                            MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then you can set your test class like this:

```
public class TestDBSeeder : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<LocabalSqlContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(LocabalSqlContext context)
    {
        Locabal.Model.Migrations.Configuration.SeedData(context);
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class LocabalSqlContextIntegrationBaseTest
{
    protected TransactionScope Transaction { get; set; }

    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void Init(TestContext c)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<LocabalSqlContext>(new TestDBSeeder());

        if (!Database.Exists("LocabalSqlContext"))
        {
            using (var db = new LocabalSqlContext())
            {
                db.Database.Initialize(true);
            }
        }
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public virtual void StartDbTransaction()
    {
        Transaction = new TransactionScope();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public virtual void EndDbTransaction()
    {
        Transaction.Dispose();
    }
}
```