# Basic EntityFramework Testing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I'm relatively new to EntityFramework and really want to get into testing things before I get too much further into things and have a huge codebase to retrospectively write tests for. I've not used it much and so methods are fairly basic, like below;

```
public Employee GetEmployee(int employeeID)
{
    using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        return db.Employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.idEmployee == employeeID);
    }
}
```

This is fine in my app, but in my test project, it doesn't work because the test project doesn't seem to read the app.config file and so there's no connection string for `DatabaseContext` to use. I've read a bit about testing, nothing seems really definitive, though this [post](http://romiller.com/2012/02/14/testing-with-a-fake-dbcontext/) is the "official" way to do things (it's linked to from MSDN. The post seems fairly involved though and would require me to do things a lot differently than what I currently am, unless I've misunderstood some of it?

Could someone help clear this up for me? I can't even cheat and copy app.config across to the test project, it still doesn't read it (I've also tried renaming to MyApp.exe.config and still no luck). Is my GetEmployee method wrong? Should I do something more like the linked post? Or is there some way to test that I've not found yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the information people, found some interesting hints and tips through the various links supplied. In the end, I tried out this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx) from MSDN, funnily enough! Though it says it's for EF6, it does actually work for previous versions. The reason it indicates EF6 is for async stuff.

Answer (score 0):

@FizzBuzz - here is another article the discusses how to setup your unit test projects to work with entity framework:

[How to get Entity Framework to read my app.config file in Unit Test project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101901/how-to-get-entity-framework-to-read-my-app-config-file-in-unit-test-project)

Comment: It's a start...but I really shouldn't be testing with a live database anyway. It's a bad idea to test update/insert/delete methods on a live database for one. Plus it's always changing. So it would be better to figure out the mocking side of things...

Comment: given that it easy simple to create a new Empty DataBase seems to me that testing is either against a test Db or you implement a custom provider.  Why does testing require the production DB?

Comment: @FizzBuzz - yes, you can definitely utilize Fakes for your entity framework DbContext versus a live development/test database.

Comment: Yes, the question is how, based on the currently implementation (see the code snippet in my question). As far as I can tell, I would have to make some decent changes to be able to use Fakes, but I've never tested before, so I have no idea where to start or if that's even the right option.

Answer (score 0):

You can read one approach for integration testing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334626/integration-testing-database-am-i-doing-it-right/20341124#20341124).
About the config issue setting `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy Always` should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

There are to options to resolve the issue you are facing.

**Option 1:** Create a mock for the app.config values. for mocking you can use Rhino Mock

**Option 2:** In your Unit Test project : Right click on the project > Add > Existing Item > 
              Select File > Add it as a link.

[image]

Comment: Will look up Rhino Mock, thanks for the info. EF seems to hard-code where to look into the auto-generated files though, so I'm not sure this is the right solution. I've also tried "Add As Link" with no success, lending more weight to my thoughts that mocking the app.config won't work. I have however figured out mocking, will post my answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go with your live database (and right so!), then you basically have two options:

1. Use another database (must be of the same kind as your live db,
   since EF doesn't allow for changing the db system, only its
   location) and add another app.config to your unit test project
   (which is the same as in your live project except that the db
   connection string is different).
2. Use the [NDbUnit](https://code.google.com/p/ndbunit/) framework, which
   allows for defining the data in xml files. Here also you'll need an
   individual app.config for your test project, if you don't want to hardcode the test data connection string. (This approach is only
   advisable, if your live db has no or only very few schema changes,
   because NDbUnit is quite allergic to these.) I wrote a blog post (with sample solution) about this approach [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/529830/TestingplusEntityplusFrameworkplusapplications-2cp).

A third approach would be to mock all EF stuff, but this quickly gets overly complicated (you can find this also in a previous part of the above mentioned post, if you're interested).

HTH
Thomas